# Yapsy: a simple hack to get rid of the plugin info file

Tags: python, plugins

I'd like to use a plugin system within my code. I've looked around for simple (yet powerful) python modules, and found Yapsy (among some others).

It is quite what I was looking for, but the way Yapsy discover plugins is not very flexible and require a plugin info file to be present. I'd like to get rid of it, without having to fork the code (if I start relying on Yapsy, I want to be sure I'll get all the updates from it without having to refork it each time).

I came out with this quick and dirty solution which is working fine, but do not improve the flexibility of the "discovering" process:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os
import logging
from cStringIO import StringIO

from yapsy.PluginManager import PluginManager
from yapsy.IPlugin import IPlugin
from yapsy.PluginInfo import PluginInfo


class MyPluginManager(PluginManager):
    """
    My attempt to get rid of the plugin info file...
    """
    def __init__(self, 
                 categories_filter={"Default":IPlugin}, 
                 directories_list=None, 
                 plugin_info_ext="plugin.py"):
        """
        Initialize the mapping of the categories and set the list of
        directories where plugins may be. This can also be set by
        direct call the methods: 

        - ``setCategoriesFilter`` for ``categories_filter``
        - ``setPluginPlaces`` for ``directories_list``
        - ``setPluginInfoExtension`` for ``plugin_info_ext``

        You may look at these function's documentation for the meaning
        of each corresponding arguments.
        """
        self.setPluginInfoClass(PluginInfo)
        self.setCategoriesFilter(categories_filter)     
        self.setPluginPlaces(directories_list)
        self.setPluginInfoExtension(plugin_info_ext)    

    def _gatherCorePluginInfo(self, directory, filename):
        """
        Gather the core information (name, and module to be loaded)
        about a plugin described by it's info file (found at
        'directory/filename').

        Return an instance of ``self.plugin_info_cls`` and the
        config_parser used to gather the core data *in a tuple*, if the
        required info could be localised, else return ``(None,None)``.

        .. note:: This is supposed to be used internally by subclasses
            and decorators.

        """
        # now we can consider the file as a serious candidate
        candidate_infofile = os.path.join(directory,filename)
        print candidate_infofile

        # My hack : just create a StringIO file with basic plugin info
        _fname = filename.rstrip(".py")
        _file = StringIO()
        _file.write("""[Core]
Name = %s
Module = %s
        """ % (_fname, _fname))
        _file.seek(0)

        # parse the information file to get info about the plugin
        name,moduleName,config_parser = self._getPluginNameAndModuleFromStream(_file, candidate_infofile)
        print name, moduleName, config_parser
        if (name,moduleName,config_parser)==(None,None,None):
                        return (None,None)
        # start collecting essential info
        plugin_info = self._plugin_info_cls(name,os.path.join(directory,moduleName))
        return (plugin_info,config_parser)
```

This hack just assumes that the plugin has an extension ".plugin.py" (or ".plugin" for directory, but I did not test it). Then I create a cSringIO file to fool Yapsy and make it think he found a plugin info file. (One can still provide additional informations in the plugin by setting the proper variables: author, description...).

I'm wondering if there is a better way or if people have already done that. This hack is clearly too rough to be really useful, and I'd like to have something more flexible: a plugin may be discovered by its plugin info file (as in the original code) or by a pattern for the plugin name (probably using `re`, allowing the usage of prefix, suffix...). As far as I see, having these ideas implemented would require a much more complex hack than what I've already done...

Comment: Instead of packing the info as a fake file that needs to be parsed, why not generate your own `PluginInfo` object based on the information you gathered? If nothing else, it would be less hacky. Also, you should probably call `PluginManager.__init__()` from your `__init__`

Comment: @alexis Thanks for your suggestion. But generating the PluginInfo would require a much more complex hack (it would require the change of more than one class/method). As for the `PluginManager.__init__()`, you're right, but here I've just copied all the content of the original method so this is not required (it is a dirty/quick hack :)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've implemented a fork of the Yapsy plugin manager, and am actually in touch with the author of the package. As soon as the documentation and tests are done, I think this may be included in the next release of Yapsy.

Comment: It's been integrated within Yapsy. Look at the docs: http://yapsy.sourceforge.net/#modify-plugin-descriptions-and-detections

Comment: A small example (here or in the docs) would be sweet! Thanks for your work. :)